# Dashed Arrow Head Filled With Color

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

I have used konvajs for creating a Konva.Arrow shape using dashed line. However, the arrow head is not filled with color. How can I get the arrow head to have a color?

Here is the basis of the code I use to make the arrow.

```
lineConfig['dash'] = [12, 8];
lineConfig['points'] = [pos.x, pos.y];
arrowLine = new Konva.Arrow(lineConfig);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the `fill` property to your arrow too, something like `fill: 'black'`. I tried to draw an arrow without that property and I got the same result as you described.

Here is the working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@7.2.5/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Konva Arrow Demo</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: width,
        height: height
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();

      var arrow = new Konva.Arrow({
        x: stage.width() / 4,
        y: stage.height() / 4,
        points: [0, 0, 10, 100],
        pointerLength: 20,
        dash: [12, 8],
        pointerWidth: 20,
        // Comment the following line to get your issue
        fill: "black",
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 4
      });

      // add the shape to the layer
      layer.add(arrow);

      // add the layer to the stage
      stage.add(layer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```